# Postman test fails test for array when array with one item is returned

Tags: postman

I have a postman test case:

```
pm.test("Check for property of type null or array", function(){
    var isNullOrArray = (property === null || typeof(property) === "array");
    pm.expect(isNullOrArray, "property is of type " + typeof(property)).to.be.true;
});
```

Unfortunately, when I mock a response that returns an array with only one item like this:

```
"property": [
    {
        "user_id": 1234,
        "is_true": false
    }
 ]
```

The test fails and in the logs I can see that typeof(property) is an object.

The test seems to work with other responses that have more than one item in the array. What's wrong with my test? Is `typeof(property) === "array"` even possible? Or is it possible the array is not recognized because there is just the one object inside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array.isArray instead , in javascript type of array returns object as everything is an object in javascript except primitive types ( means only immutable data types are considered as non objects )

```
pm.test("Check for property of type null or array", function(){
    var isNullOrArray = (property === null || Aarray.isArray(property));
    pm.expect(isNullOrArray, "property is of type " + typeof(property)).to.be.true;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive , array is not primitve data type so is considered as an object

```
a = [1,2,3]

b =a

a[2] = 5

console.log(b)
```

you can see that changing 'a' changes 'b' as they are mutable , and thus its a object

Comment: I don't know how it passed for other response could you add an example that passed it shouldn't pass

Comment: @PHide, you're right, it always fails. I must have imagined the passes...

Comment: @PHide, you're solution works! Thanks also for the explanation regarding the types!

Comment: @nemu could you accept the answer by clicking the tick sign